# How do I make the stackoverflow "filters" tab go away?

Tags: interface

I love stackoverflow.

I don't need "filters" (read "themes"). I know the tab sits bottom-right, but it's annoying.

I want that tab to go away (forever). Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Discussion, support, and feature requests for this site should be posted to [meta] instead.

Comment: It's an April Fool's joke. It will go away soon I'm sure.

Comment: There's a bar at the bottom, the left most of the central icons has a circle with a cross in it, which will turn off the page theme. If you still see a black bar, there's a cancel cross at the right hand side. There's a so meta question about this, if you scroll down the answers, there's images to help: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416982/how-do-i-disable-stack-overflow-filters-the-april-fools-themes

Comment: in the bottom-right of the screen, there is an icon named filters .click on it and the list of filters will show up. choose the first one